# How to find input_function for a postgres type

Tags: postgresql

Postgres types are created with an `input_function`, which defines how to convert a text representation of the type to the internal representation. How can I find the name of the `input_function` for a given type?

In particular I'm looking for what happens when you do `::date`, but I'm also interested in the general answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`pg_type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html) in PostgreSQL documentation.

```
=# select typname, typinput,typoutput from pg_type where typname='date';

 typname | typinput | typoutput 
---------+----------+-----------
 date    | date_in  | date_out
```